# Color style in the RGB field without “#” or how to copy part of the text from one field to another in the layer attributes?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

How to insert the color of the style without the key "#" in the field 'CLRRGB' ([Reefmaster](https://reefmaster.com.au/) does not understand "#" but QGIS does not understand when without "#"). Forced to leave two attributes. With the help of the script, I fill in the layer style in 'QGIS_COLOR'. I need another script so that in the field 'CLRRGB' was the same color only without the "#".

[image]

Perhaps craftsmen can improve this script:

```
prefix = "'"
layer = iface.activeLayer()
attr = layer.renderer().classAttribute()
attrColor = 'QGIS_COLOR' # Название поля для хранения цветов
fieldIndex = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(attrColor)
attrFeatMap = {}

for cat in layer.renderer().categories(): 
  expr = "\""+attr+"\"="+prefix+unicode(cat.value())+prefix
  for f in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression(expr))):
    attrMap = { fieldIndex : cat.symbol().color().name()}
    attrFeatMap[ f.id() ] = attrMap

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues( attrFeatMap )
```

Comment: how about expr = "\""+attr+"\"="+prefix+unicode("#"+cat.value())+prefix

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsSingleSymbolRenderer' object has no attribute 'classAttribute'